# What is the cost of deletion of a record from a Child table having foreign key constraint with parent table

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

For instance there are 20 tables which have foreign key of a table let's call it Child. Now when i delete a record from Child it will check whether the record is referenced from somewhere or not, is it so or some other scenario.
My question is how this foreign key relation impacting performance of deletion operation.

Actually i'm using hibernate and i have an entity which has got only 3 columns and is used in many other Entities(one-to-one) mapping. 
I'm thinking to make this entity embeddable for performance tuning because if i keep it entity then mapping between tables is done using foreign key. Although when i delete an entity there are only two query are running :- delete parent , then delete child. But as child's foreign key is referenced from many other tables with lot of records so it will check whether reference of record in child exists in some tables or not if not then delete while deleting child record. So i want to target this issue by making child embeddable which will result columns of child will be included in parent tables. Whether this will help?

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends very much on which DBMS you're using, how your tables are designed, indexed and stored, and how much data you have.

In general, foreign key constraints save time and effort and prevent mistakes.  Without a foreign key constraint, you would have to enforce integrity yourself.

For example, manually cascading a delete or update would be done in multiple round-trips to the database which would normally be wrapped in a transaction.  Manually checking for related records to restrict changes would also require additional queries and data transferred between server and client.

If you missed anything or another user modified related data between your queries, you might end up with invalid data, which can be very costly - both in terms of DBA time as well as customer satisfaction.

Comment: I have edited my question now let me know your advice

Comment: Sorry, I don't use object-relational mappers and can't advise on your situation.  I will remove my answer if you feel it isn't relevant.